# positive elements and norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a abelian $C^∗$-algebra and $a,b$ are elements in $A$ such that $0‎≤‎a‎≤‎1,0‎≤‎b‎≤‎1‎‎$
‎‎ then $0‎≤‎\|a-b \|≤‎1‎$.

My problem is:"Does the same hold if $A$ is not abelian?"

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You have
$$
-1\leq -b\leq a-b\leq a\leq1.
$$

Comment: .The closed subspace generated by polynomials in $a$ is a commutative $C^*$ algebra, which can be identified with the space of continuous $f : S_a\to C$ for some compact $T_2$ space $S_a$ so  "$0\leq a\leq 1$" has an obvious meaning. Similarly for $b$ and for $a-b$. But if $a b\ne b a$ then what does $a-b\leq a$ mean? ( Since $S_{a-b}$ and $S_a$ are different spaces.)

Comment: "$0\leq a\leq1$"  has an obvious meaning in **any** unital C $^*$-algebra. Same with $x\leq y $ for selfadjoint $x,y $.

Comment: You show ‎$‎‎-1‎\leq ‎a-b‎\leq1‎‎$.yes ‎that ‎is ‎okay.‎
but I ‎‎want to ‎show that ‎‎$‎‎‎0\leq\|a-b\|‎\leq 1‎‎$.‎
you ‎know ‎that ‎if  ‎‎$‎‎0‎\leq c‎\leq d‎‎$ ‎then ‎‎$‎‎\|c\|‎\leq \|d\|‎$‎

Comment: Uh? $0\leq \|a-b\|$ is always true no matter what $a$ and $b$ are. The inequality I showed you implies that $\sigma(a-b)\subset [-1,1]$,which immediately implies that $\|a-b\|\leq1$.